# Projector problems in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics, hp, projector

I have problem related to Projectors whenever I try to use projector for slides "PowerPoint in a class", it connects and disconnects suddenly so normally I can't use the projector at all. I want to give classes and I don't want to go back to Windows 7 which was fine with the projectors.

My System info is
Hp Elitebook 8440p
Intel Graphics
Corei5 2.4 GHz
OS Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: Can you be more specific please? You plug-in the Projector, then do you change settings manually, do you use a special key on your Notebook?

Comment: I plug-in the Projector then I press Command or Start + p, it works for sometime then it disconnect form the projector and I didn't change any settings manually. @BenjaminMaurer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the configuration with the menu and not the hot-key.

### Open `System Settings`

You can either open it with the cogwheel symbol in the upper right corner -> System Settings...

Or you just open the menu and type "System Settings".

### Open the `Displays` configuration

In the "System Settings" menu, there is a monitor icon that reads `Displays`, open that menu.

### Change display settings

Your projector is like a second display. You should see a "buit-in display" for your notebook and a second display for your projector.
Click on it and switch it to "On".
You can then change settings if you want to have the two screens running, then it they will behave as if it was one big screen. That means you have to move the presentation window to the projector display. Or you can just mirror them and they will show the same stuff. You can also turn your internal display to "off" and just use the projector.

There is also some [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html), but it doesn't say more than I just did.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin Maurer your method is working great, but Some of projectors does not show the name of the projector it shows "unknown" but for the others it works like a charm. Thanks.